Multi-Environment Configs Failed on Craft cms 5
I am trying to implement [Multi-Environment Configs][1] on my Craft CMS 5. i've change my general.php to this. But i always got error {"name":"Not Found","message":"Page not found.","code":0,"status":404,"type":"yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException"}. does anyone have a solution for this?
return [
    '*' => [
        // Applies to all environments:
        'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'allowAdminChanges' => false,
    ],

    'dev' => [
        // Only applies to development environments, overriding anything in `*`:
        'allowAdminChanges' => true,
        'devMode' => true,
    ],

    'production' => [
        // Only applies to the production environment, overriding anything in `*`:
        'cpTrigger' => 'secret-word',
    ],
];


  [1]: https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/configure.html#multi-environment-configs


Which page are you trying to open? If it’s the Control Panel, and you've followed the configuration in the documentation, then your Control Panel URL should be localhost:{port}/secret-word and your front-end URL should be: localhost:{port}. Unless you have additional configurations beyond those in the documentation, I'm not entirely sure what's causing the "Not Found" error.

update: the CP Url in Dev environment should be: localhost:{port}/admin and Production should be localhost:{port}/secret-word

The keys in the array returned from the multi-env config are matched to the value for the CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT environment variable (excluding the asterisk *, which contains configuration that should apply in all environments).
That means that for the configuration below the 'production' key in your multi-env config file to apply in your production environment, the production environment needs a CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT=production environment variable (typically set in a .env file at the root of your Craft install).
